# Does a derived class implement the interfaces of the base class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Do derived classes implement the interfaces of the base class?

Example:

```
interface IBase {
    controls : { [key: string] : number }
}

class BaseClass implements IBase {
    controls = {};
}

class TestClass extends BaseClass {
    controls = {test:'a'};
}
```

The above does not complain when setting a control value to a string in the derived class when the interface states that it should be a number.

If I set controls to null in the derived class, it does complain with:

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{}'

Is the correct way to implement the interface in every derived class and the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a class `implements` an interface, it doesn't actually affect the type of the class.  The compiler *checks* that the class is compatible with the interface, but it doesn't use the interface as context to give types to the class's members.  If you write `class Foo implements Bar {...}` and there is no compiler error, then it will be treated the same by the compiler as if you'd left out `implements Bar` and just wrote `class Foo {...}`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and issues linked within for more information.

So `BaseClass`'s `controls` property is inferred to have the empty object type `{}`.  You might have expected `BaseClass`'s `controls` property to be of type `{ [key: string] : number }`, but that doesn't happen because such information would only come from the  `implements IBase` clause, which is ignored when giving types to `BaseClass`'s members.  If you want to see an implementing class or a subclass have properties with particular types, you should annotate them:

```
class BaseClass implements IBase {
    controls: { [key: string]: number } = {}; // annotated
}

class TestClass extends BaseClass {
    // you might also want to annotate this, depending on intent
    controls = { test: 'a' }; // error!
}
```

---

It's also important to note that, for better or worse, TypeScript's type system is not fully [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness); there are some "holes" where TypeScript allows assignments that are *inconsistent*.

In a sound type system, [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) should be [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation); that means, for any types `A`, `B`, and `C`, if `A extends B` and `B extends C`, then `A extends C`.  And while this is quite often the case in TypeScript, it is sometimes violated.  This is what's happening in your example: `TestClass extends BaseClass`, and `BaseClass extends IBase`, but `TestClass` does not extend `IBase`.

If we make a helper type function `VerifyExtends<T, U>` that only compiles if `T extends U`, we can witness this intransitivity of subtyping ourselves:

```
type VerifyExtends<T extends U, U> = void;    
type AB = VerifyExtends<TestClass, BaseClass> // okay
type BC = VerifyExtends<BaseClass, IBase> // okay
type AC = VerifyExtends<TestClass, IBase> // error!
```

`TestClass extends BaseClass` because the `controls` property in `TestClass` has an extra property that is not mentioned in that of `BaseClass` (`{}`), and you are allowed to extend object types by adding properties.

And `BaseClass extends TestClass` because its `controls` property `{}` has properties that conflict with the index signature (it has no properties at all)... and TypeScript will give [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) to such types.

But of course, `TestClass` does not extend `IBase` because extra properties and implicit index signatures are not mutually consistent.  So we have weirdness.

---

In your case, I'd probably suggest explicit annotations, since that is your intent.  But you will likely run into unsoundness sooner or later, and you should be prepared for it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcUG8CwAUMicggPbhTkA2WAXMrsgNoDWEAno1mFKAHMAuoxABXALYAjaMgC+RBYSIg4EiFgAOiFAEEQIcmDiQmRIqTI1sWZJhwBha1lvAJmmhHXhbGbHgtLUgoqWgYmVg5uZF5+EGFRSRkoeWQAXiY5AG5kAHpc5DgDIxMIABNAkiVKqxtkABUNMCc6iAAPSBAy23sIFpczYiCSEL4w9IjIXkYAcjgZ+Rz85GhqKABCGurCbaIEZx7-ftd3T28wX17By1HqOgncbMVzQn26xt5jlY6ILsPHA7XYKUMb3DLMKZgWbzRZ5AqrcgbZ7KQhgTiaFAANWgwBgnAAoj8-gAeerfTrdZAAVQANNSAHwTABu5GAZSyLzRGOQAA0Jtj+HjCRSsMTesc6X4cIzluQ2HBOEQuSgAJr8nFCondUlNCV2I4HGUFOUKpXolAALXVgoJWtFH2aB0lvSNKyga02hCAA)